# Key of max value in a dict

Tags: python, python-3.x

This gives the max value in a dict, but how do I get the dict key for the max value?

```
max([d[i] for i in d])
```

Comment: NB `max(d[i] for i in d)` is conceptually simpler (and more memory-efficient) and `max(d.values())` is clearer IMHO.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the [`key=` keyword argument to `max()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max):

```
max(d, key=lambda k: d[k])
```

Instead of the lambda you can use `operators.itemgetter` as well:

```
import operators
max(d, key=operators.itemgetter(d))
```

or pass in `d.get`:

```
max(d, key=d.get)
```

Comment: but what if there is multiple keys has the max value?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's safe to use == for comparison in this case, which might not always be true e.g. with floats.

```
d = { 'a' : 2, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 1}

max_val = max(d.values())
max_keys = [k for k, v in d.items() if v == max_val]

print(max_keys)
```

gives,

```
['a', 'b']

[Program finished]
```